# How long should I dry fresh seeds from solanaceae, cucurbitaceae and other families, before storing?

Tags: vegetables, seeds, seed-saving, technique

I'm collecting a bunch of wet seeds (tomatoes, tomatillos, zucchini, peppers, cantaloupe, cucumber, winter squash, etc.) I'm drying them out for storage. I have to dry them indoors, with only a limited amount of sun, because there's snow and stuff outside. **How long should I dry them before bagging them up and storing them?** I just don't want them to mold or some such.

I'm not looking for instructions on saving seeds, germination (how drying affects germination rates), methods of drying (paper plates vs. paper bags and stuff) and all that. I'm just wondering about how long to dry them so I can bag them up without worry of mold and all that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dry them out of direct sunlight, in a room-temperature, very dry place. Place them in a single layer on a paper towel over a tray/plate, and let them dry for 7-10 days. Some solanaceous seeds (ie, tomatoes) are coated in gel, and so are best [fermented](http://www.douggreensgarden.com/tomato-seed-fermentation.html) before drying, to kill disease, and clean the seeds. They will also be easier to remove from the drying position.